# Click detection + Command: Pynput

Tags: python, detection, pynput

So, I'm working on something with pynput and I want it so every time I click it prints a different word like:

```
Click:
Print("HI")
Click:
Print("WHY")
Click:
Print("BYE")
```

But the code I'm using is:

```
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print(c.format(
        print("HI - Clicked")
        if pressed else
        print("HI - Unclicked"),
        (x, y)))
    if not pressed:
        # Stop listener
        return False
with Listener(
        on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

So after it says ("HI - Unclicked") and you click again I want it to say ("WHY - Clicked") and ("WHY - Unclicked") If anyone knows how PLEASEEE Reply, EDIT: And please show me how to play an audio for the click and unclick with the list like: ['food.wav', 'click.wav'] Thank you.

Comment: Can you show an example of the current output you're getting versus what you expect?

Comment: Remember that the `print` returns `None`.  Inside your `c.format`, you should have strings, not `print` functions.

Comment: And of course, if you kill the listener as soon as you get the first unclilck, then you'll never get another click.

Answer (score 0):

You just keep a list of your greetings and rotate through them.

```
greets = ["HI", "WHY", "BYE"]
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    greet = greets[0]
    if pressed:
        print(greet, "- Clicked", x, y )
    else:
        print(greet, "- Unclicked", x, y )
        greets.append(greets.pop(0))

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Update

```
greets = ["gunshot.wav", "you.wav", "cool.wav"]
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    greet = greets[0]
    if pressed:
        pg.mixer.Sound(greet).play()
        print(greet, "- Clicked", x, y )
    else:
        print(greet, "- Unclicked", x, y )
        greets.append(greets.pop(0))

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Or even:

```
greets = [pg.mixer.Sound(k) for k in ("gunshot.wav", "you.wav", "cool.wav")]
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    greet = greets[0]
    if pressed:
        greet.play()
        print("- Clicked", x, y )
    else:
        print("- Unclicked", x, y )
        greets.append(greets.pop(0))

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I play the audio with the names of the list when I click?

Comment: Who said anything about audio?  You never mentioned that.  Do you already have sound in your app?

Comment: Yes, I do have the audio, And I forgot to put play and audio too sorry.

Comment: Well, I don't know what audio package you're using.  If you have a text-to-speech module, you can just pass the `greet` string to that.

Comment: I'm not using TTS, I'm using pygame's audio function like:
```
ran = pg.mixer.Sound('text.wav')
ran.play()
```

Comment: `pygame`'s audio functions just play canned audio files.  You can't make it speak.  You would need a TTS module.

Comment: Yes I know, I want the list "Greet" To have the name of the files that are going to play like,

greets = ["gunshot.wav", "you.wav", "cool.wav"]ran = pg.mixer.Sound(greets)
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    greet = greets[0]
    if pressed:
        ran.play()
    else:
        print(greet, "- Unclicked", x, y )
        greets.append(greets.pop(0))

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join() but that doesn't work

Comment: No, of course not.  You have to play them individually.  I'll update it.

Comment: Ok thanks Ill try

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/777192508319989770/912471373870411786/unknown.png <-- Picture of the error I used the (for k in)

Comment: And did you not know how to fix that little typo on my part?  I've fixed it above.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: You have to do better than that if you're going to get help.